# EXCEPTION: No provider for Router! Using angular-cli with latest @angular/router(3.0.0-beat.2)

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-cli

I created angular 2 project with angular-cli@1.0.0-beat.9 with --mobile flag.
It throws an error every time I try to launch the local server.

> {PROJECT_NAME}/tmp/broccoli_type_script_compiler-cache_path-3pQ1Aw4o.tmp/src/app/app.component.js class AppComponent - inline template:3:6
>
> EXCEPTION: No provider for Router!

```
{ //package.json
"dependencies": {
 "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
 "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
 "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
 "@angular/forms": "^0.2.0",
 "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
 "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
 "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
 "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.2",
 "es6-shim": "0.35.1",
 "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
 "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
 "systemjs": "0.19.26",
 "zone.js": "0.6.12"
},
"devDependencies": {
 "@angular/app-shell": "0.0.0",
 "@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0-rc.4",
 "@angular/service-worker": "0.2.0",
 "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.9",
 "angular2-broccoli-prerender": "0.11.0",
 "angular2-universal": "0.104.5",
 "angular2-universal-polyfills": "0.4.1",
 "codelyzer": "0.0.20",
 "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "1.4.0",
 "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
 "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
 "karma": "0.13.22",
 "karma-chrome-launcher": "0.2.3",
 "karma-jasmine": "0.3.8",
 "parse5": "^1.5.0",
 "preboot": "2.1.2",
 "protractor": "3.3.0",
 "ts-node": "0.5.5",
 "tslint": "3.11.0",
 "typescript": "1.8.10",
 "typings": "0.8.1"
 }
}
```

This is how [my application](http://plnkr.co/HczVb264Mg2TXEboNBq2) structured. (Will no work, only Showing the structure of the application).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you added ROUTER_DIRECTIVE in directive in component metadata

Comment: @ArpitAgarwal yes! I have already added that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add ROUTER_DIRECTIVES inside directives, something like this:

```
directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
```

Comment: You're rgith, sorry! I didn't see the plunker. But for me this plunker doesn't work. It throws an error in console.

Comment: @ReginaldoCamargoRibeiro, `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` is no longer available to use in the latest [release](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/router/index.ts).